# How to iterate over an array a certain amount of times?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, iteration

```
array = [apple, orange]    
number = 4
```

desired output:

```
apple    
orange    
apple    
orange
```

So far, I have:

```
array.each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

I'm just not sure how to iterate over the array 4 times.

Answer (score 8):

```
array = ["apple", "orange"]
iter_count = 4
array.cycle.take(iter_count).each { |x|
  puts x
}
```

`array.cycle` gives us an infinite enumerable that repeats the elements of `array`. Then we take the first `iter_count` elements from it and iterate over that.

[`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html) has a ton of goodies that perform neat tasks like this. Once you familiarize yourself with the module, you'll find you can do a lot of array- and stream- oriented processes much more easily.

Comment: This is interesting but seems overly complex when Ruby already has the `times` method. A few other points 1) You've mentioned `numOfIteration` but it's not anywhere in your code snippet. 2) `array.cycle` returns an Enumerator instance.

Answer (score 4):

```rb
ar = ["apple", "orange"]
n = 4
n.times { ar.each{|a| p a} }
```

Comment: Even simpler `4.times { puts array }`

Comment: It's not exactly what was required. Your code will output 8 lines, but it's needed 4

Comment: @MikDiet yeah I was uncertain, b/c the question says "iterate over the array 4 times", but the example output shows iterating 2 times. So I made an interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

```
array = ["apple", "orange"]
numOfIteration=4
for i in 0..numOfIteration-1
   puts array[i%array.size]
end
```

Comment: This is pretty unidiomatic Ruby code. `for` loops are generally discouraged and we also use snake_case for variable names. So in your case `num_of_iterarions`. Nonetheless this code does work and is a valid answer :)

Comment: It's true Sagar and yet it's still part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

A fun way to achieve this:

```
4.times { |n| p array[n % array.count] }
```

Definitely not the best: every iteration we are counting the number of elements in array and also processing that n is dividable by the number of elements. It's also not very readable, as there is some cognitive processing required to understand the statement.

A nicer way to achieve this:

```
print(arr.cycle.take(4).join("\n"))
apple
orange
apple
orange
```

Comment: `puts arr.cycle.take(4)` produces the same output

Answer (score 0):

another non-idiomatic for loop, 3 dots removes need for explicit subtraction

```
array = ['apple', 'orange']
number = 4

for i in 0...number
  puts array[i % array.size]
end
```

and some silliness with lambdas and recursion :D

```
array = ['apple', 'orange']
number = 4

loop = lambda do |list, count|
  return if count == number

  puts list[count % list.size]

  loop.(list, count + 1)
end

loop.(array, 0)
```